# After UIImage rotation white lines appear

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I face a problem when after `UIImage` rotation the white lines appear on sides of the image. In my image redactor I have rotateButton. After tapping on it I call this function:

```
func rotateLeft() -> UIImage? {

    let radians = CGFloat.rotateRadians
    
    // Calculate the size of the rotated image
    var rotatedSize = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        .applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians))
        .integral.size

    // Round the dimensions to the nearest whole number
    rotatedSize.width = round(rotatedSize.width)
    rotatedSize.height = round(rotatedSize.height)

    // Create a context for the rotated image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }

    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        // Move the origin to the center of the image
        context.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width / 2.0, y: rotatedSize.height / 2.0)
        
        // Rotate the context
        context.rotate(by: radians)
        
        // Draw the image
        draw(in: CGRect(
            x: -size.width / 2.0,
            y: -size.height / 2.0,
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height)
        )
        
        // Get the rotated image from the context
        if let rotatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
            return rotatedImage
        }
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

This function return rotated image, after what I just animate image in `UIImageVIew`, and in completion I assigns this new rotate image to UIImageView (everything works fine, I think).
But the problem is that if I spam this button many times (button tap only work when previous rotation logic finished), the white lines become bigger and bigger. [image]

I read that a problem is cause of floting points after rotation, so I tried to `round` size, but it doesn't help.
So can someone explain what Is a problem, or give me some  link where I can read about this problem.

P.S. When I use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` it works much slower than previous deprecated method:

```
func rotateLeft() -> UIImage? {

    let radians = CGFloat.rotateRadians

    // Calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space

    let rotatedSize = CGSize(width: size.height, height: size.width)

    // Create the renderer with the rotatedSize
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: rotatedSize)

    // Perform the rotation transformation within the image renderer context
    let rotatedImage = renderer.image { context in
        context.cgContext.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width / 2.0, y: rotatedSize.height / 2.0)
        context.cgContext.rotate(by: radians)

        // Translate and rotate the graphics context
        let origin = CGPoint(x: -size.width / 2, y: -size.height / 2)

        // Draw the original image in the rotated context
        draw(at: origin)
    }

    return rotatedImage
}
```

The problem with `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` was that it automatically take iPhone scale(in my case 3), so image 2000x1000 became 6000x3000. You need to setup scale factor to 1, in renderer.

Comment: Note that `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` and `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_:_:_:)` are deprecated. You should use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CGRect function `applying(_ t: CGAffineTransform) -> CGRect` doesn't return meaningful values for rotations unless they are multiples of 90°, and even then, you might get floating point errors. Does your app support arbitrary rotation angles? If not, I would suggest either leaving the rectangle the same size for 180° rotations, or just swapping the height and width for 90° rotations.

That should preserve your image without introducing white bars on the sides, since you'll always be rendering your image into a rect with the exact number of pixels.

Comment: Yes, changing width to height and height to width helped, and it sounds logica since we just rotate image on 90 degree. White line isn't appear anymore.
But still I don't clearly understand the problem with floating points. I tried to `floor` width and height, but white lines still were there.

Comment: If you want to figure out what's going on, log the height and width before and after the rotation. I think you'll find that the numbers are changing slightly, and if one dimension changes and the other doesn't change in proportion, Core Image will leave empty space on the sides in order to preserve the aspect ratio of the image.